# gradle dependency returns a rar file, not a jar file

Tags: maven, gradle

I have a Gradle project where I have a dependency on 'net.java.xadisk:xadisk:1.2.2'

Gradle do not download the 'jar' file. The problem (I think) is that the XADisk POM file packaging is 'rar'. Only the 'rar' file is downloaded to the gradle local cache and not the 'jar' file.

XADisks POM.xml

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>net.java.xadisk</groupId>
    <artifactId>xadisk</artifactId>
    <packaging>rar</packaging>        
    ...    
<project>
```

Example build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    // http://jcenter.bintray.com/net/java/xadisk/xadisk/1.2.2/
    compile "net.java.xadisk:xadisk:1.2.2"
}
```

How can I make gradle download the jar file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    // http://jcenter.bintray.com/net/java/xadisk/xadisk/1.2.2/
    compile "net.java.xadisk:xadisk:1.2.2@jar"
}

task copyDeps(type: Copy) {
   from configurations.compile
   into 'deps'
}
```

[Here](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#artifactOnly) are the docs.